# How do I construct a simple function where all I need to provide is a variable

Tags: function

I'm curious about why this works:

```
    fc <- function(s, i){  
      s <- data[i,]
      return(mean(s$V1, na.rm=T))
    }
    bootmean <- boot(data, fc, R=500)
```

But this does not:

```
    fc <- function(s, i, x){  
      s <- data[i,]
      return(mean(s$x, na.rm=T))
    }
    bootmean <- boot(data, fc, R=500, x=V1)
```

Where `V1` is a variable in a data frame. I'm basically trying to create a function where I only have to provide

```
    bootmean <- boot(data, fc, R=500, x=V1)
```

and it performs the function on the variable I provide.

Example `Data =`

```
    ID      V1
    1       2
    2       6
    3       3
    4       2
    5       5
```

Comment: I think `s$x` means getting the column literally named "x". Try `s[x]` if the column name is stored in the variable `x`

Comment: It would be a really good idea to add the tag for the language you're using.